# How to find a substring in only a portion of a std::string?

Tags: c++, c++98

I have a `std::string` and i want to be able to find text only in a section of it : so i need to specify a start and an end position.

In `std::string::find()` one can only specify the start position.

I am trying to find the best way to search only in a portion of `haystack`. That would consist of giving an `end_pos` to stop the search even though it doesn't reach the end of `haystack`.

**For example, search only from its 100th character to its 200th character.**

Does anybody know how I could achieve this (elegantly)?

- only by searching in `haystack` itself, not in a `substr()` of it
- without creating a copy of `haystack`
- in C++98

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: Maybe edit your answer to explain why substring isn't suitable?

Comment: `substr` isn't that good an option because of the need to copy. [`std::string_view`, on the other hand](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) allows you to specify a range of the source string and then run its own `find` member function on that range.

Comment: @littleadv I've done it thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for this approach I didn't know it could be what I'm looking for !

Comment: Smurf. That in C++98 really puts a damper on things.

Comment: @user4581301 that overload will not do what you want. It searches for substring `[s, s+count)` starting at `pos`, it does not allow you to specify where to stop searching. `std::string` does not have a ready-made method that suits your stop requirement, and since you can't use `std::string_view`, you will just have to write your own search function

Comment: Yeah. Jumped the gun a bit there. On re-read of the docs, *first **substring** equal to the range [s, s+count)*. No way built into C++98 standard string libraries.

Comment: @user4581301 nop count is the size of const CharT* s not of haystack if I understood the doc (or would it be why it got downvoted... I have to make some test)

Comment: @l_-A-_l doesn't work for reasons Remy pointed out. I misread the documentation. Explains why I was so surprised to find something that did the job so easily. Pretty much a one-liner in C++20, but that's evolution baby.

Comment: @l_-A-_l have a look at [`std::search()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I need c++98 :'(
Yep I guess I'll start to make a custom function... Thanks guys

Comment: @l_-A-_l AFAIK, `std::search()` is in C++98, but if it is not available in your compiler, it is trivial to write your own.

Comment: Not sure if this contributed to the down-voting, but I'd suggest changing *"So there is haystack.find() :"* to *"One can specify a start position, but not an end position, in `std::string::find()`:"*, if that is what you mean (I'm not sure, so I'll refrain from making the change myself). The revised version would put a summary of the situation at the very beginning of the question, and it doesn't leave people wondering what "haystack" is supposed to mean in this context. The end result is a better first impression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string` does not have a method that suits your requirement to search a sub-range of the `haystack` string. Have a look at [`std::search()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) for that instead, eg:

```cpp
std::string needle = ...;

std::string::iterator end_iter = haystack.begin() + end_pos;
std::string::iterator found_iter = std::search(haystack.begin() + start_pos, end_iter, needle.begin(), needle.end());
if (found_iter != end_iter) {
    // needle found...
}
else {
    // needle not found...
}
```

If your compiler does not have `std::search()` available, then just write your own `search()` function, such as with the implementation provided on cppreference.com, eg:

```cpp
namespace my {

template<class ForwardIt1, class ForwardIt2>
ForwardIt1 search(ForwardIt1 first, ForwardIt1 last,
                  ForwardIt2 s_first, ForwardIt2 s_last)
{
    while (1) {
        ForwardIt1 it = first;
        for (ForwardIt2 s_it = s_first; ; ++it, ++s_it) {
            if (s_it == s_last) return first;
            if (it == last) return last;
            if (!(*it == *s_it)) break;
        }
        ++first;
    }
}

}

...

std::string needle = ...;

std::string::iterator end_iter = haystack.begin() + end_pos;
std::string::iterator found_iter = my::search(haystack.begin() + start_pos, end_iter, needle.begin(), needle.end());
if (found_iter != end_iter) {
    // needle found...
}
else {
    // needle not found...
}
```

Comment: One of the things that should be taken away from in this answer is if you cannot find a utility built into class X or Library Y, look in `<algorithm>` and look at all of it. I wrote off `std::find` as not useful here, and then stopped digging. Whoops.

Comment: @user4581301 `std::find()` would not be appropriate in this situation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Man you found the needle in the haystack !! It is exactly what I needed elegant and efficient my implementation was not that good ! Merci Beaucoup !!